# Safari - how to make menubar permanently visible

Tags: macos, safari

How to make the ‘standard’ Safari /File/Edit/View 'button/menu' bar permanent  i.e. always visible at top of screen and not occasionally disappear.

I have a MacbookAir

Answer (score 0):

1. Show package contents for Safari.
2. Edit the file Contents/info.plist
3. Search for "LSUIPresentationMode" (you may want to use a plist editor). It will look like this if you use a regular text editor:
   `<key>LSUIPresentationMode</key>`
   `<integer>4</integer>`
   If the property does not exist, then you can create it - it must be inserted in the correct alphabetical order.
4. Change the value of the integer to 0, 1 or 2 (but NOT 3 or 4).
   Along with menubar permanent display, 1 also hides the dock (until mouse is moved there) and 2 removes the dock.

For more information on LSUIPresentationMode usage, [check this out](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-113616-TPXREF134).